# Pfsense web interface : 404 pages not found

Tags: firewall, pfsense, http-status-code-404

I'm using a Pfsense as a home firewall, I set it up some month before and it worked perfectly.

Now that I need to open a new port I connect to `https://pfsenseip` as usual, but this time the result is `404 page not found`.

- I have restarted from the console, but it keeps telling me 404.
- I looked at the log but can't find anything related to an error.

Have you some suggestions ?

I'm running Pfsense on zimaboard and the version is 2.6.0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue!
I have made a mistake will configuring nat for my reverse proxy.
The nat rule was pfsense (self): 443 -> myreverse: 443
This rule was overlapping all interface including my admin net. So when I try to access Web gui I end on the reverse proxy.

To correct my mistake:
Go to pfsense shell
Then exec: viconfig

Search for your nat rule and change the port to another.
Save and try to join your web GUI, if not try with a restart.

If you need a temporary extra rule to access to Web GUI you can use:
easyrule pass wan tcp 192.168.yourClientIp 192.168.pfsenseIp 443

If this post ever helps someone